# Побайтное чтение кода

Tags: ассемблер

Стоит задача написать побайтный анализ файла. Немогу понять как читать байты.

```
section .data    

title_text db 'Getting strings from file'
lengthTitle_text equ $- title_text

file_name db 'myfile.txt'
lengthFileName equ $- file_name

section .bss
info resb  1
info_size resb 1
file_disc resb  4

section .text          
global _start

_start: 

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, title_text
mov edx, lengthTitle_text
int 80h     

_rep:
mov eax, 5
mov ebx, file_name
mov ecx, 0             
mov edx, 0777          
int  0x80

mov [file_disc],eax

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, [file_disc]
mov ecx, info
mov edx, 1
int 0x80


cmp eax,0
je _exit

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, info
mov edx, 1
int 80h     

jmp _rep

_exit:
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 80h
```

Данный код постоянно выводит первый байт, а как вывести второй без вывода первого немогу понять... и т. д

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас неверно стоит метка `_rep`. Вы на каждом цикле заново открываете файл, соответственно, указатель скачет к его началу. Правильно - перенести её сюда:

```
_rep:
  mov eax, 3
  mov ebx, [file_disc]
  mov ecx, info
  mov edx, 1
  int 0x80
```

BTW, если не глазами, то этот глюк отлавливается моментально при первом же проходе по коду в отладчике. Попробуйте, отладчики - полезная штука :)